# Is the same memory allocated to all objects of class

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I was trying to build a linked list without allocating memory dynamically. Note that I can build linked list using new operator.
The below code does not work. When I debugged it I found out (as much as I can understand) that `Node a(n, head)` is allocated at the same address in the memory every time so the `a` stores pointer to itself. If someone can explain to me, it would be of great help.

```
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int n, Node *ptr = NULL) {
        val = n;
        next = ptr;
    }
};

class LinkList {
    Node *head = NULL;
public:
    void insertNode(int n) {
        Node a(n, head);
        head = &a;
    }
    void print() {
        Node* ptr = head;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            cout << ptr->val << endl;
            ptr = ptr -> next;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkList a;
    a.insertNode(3);
    a.insertNode(4);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. In the `insertNode` function the variable `a` is *local* to the function. When the function ends, so does the life-time for `a`, that object is destructed and ceases to exist. Any pointer you have to it will then become invalid, and dereferencing the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also note that `NULL` is a backward-compatibility macro from C. In C++ use `nullptr` for null pointers.

Comment: "I was trying to build a linked list without allocating memory dynamically." and you just found out why it does not work. At least not if you want to create nodes dynamically

Comment: Insert node should create a new instance of a node but not as a local variable. Use `new Node`. Also note that you are using C++ now to write the internals of a datastructure, for the most part new/delete should be fairly rare now-adays. And writing/using your own list would not be necessary, see [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: Just use `std::vector`. On rare occasions that you need something else, use another standard container.

Comment: You could in theory build a list without dynamic memory allocation (if you knew the maximum size up front). Then you just have an array of nodes and model the next not as a pointer but an index into the array.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I totally agree, but too many students still use C++ to learn about datastructures. And don't learn C++ as it should be used as a result. This really looks like a datastructures assignment.

Comment: @PepijnKramer lets make a `not-proper-C++-just-data-structure-lessons` tag :P

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Count me in :) Developing a specific language for datastructures class might be a bit too much effort today.

Comment: @PepijnKramer more seriously, as long as there is no such tag, imho `std::vector` should be mentioned. Suppose OP is trying to write C++, then there are enough online "tutorials" that could make them believe that this is the *right* way to use a linked list when you need one.

Comment: Yes that is the problem nowadays, so many legacy examples of how things had to be done in the past. And also teachers stuck pre C++11.  I can't wait for Cpp2 [Can C++ be 10x Simpler & Safer? - Herb Sutter - CppCon 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELeZAKCN4tY). Then we can forget about the legacy and focus on that simpler language that Bjarne says is waiting to get out. (I like Herb's proposal more then Carbon)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude   Thankyou.  The reason I was trying to create a linked list without  DMA was because I would not have to worry about memory leak because as the scope ends the memory for Node will be freed.  What I didn't realise that the same reason makes it not to work.

Comment: ***If*** you need to use pointers and dynamic allocation, use *smart* pointers. Like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Your bug is `head = &a;`. You attempt to store a pointer to a local stack variable `a` which has it's lifetime end when the `insertNode(int n)` function ends. The pointer you store is invalid and must not be used (undefined behavior) once this happens. This is called a dangling pointer. You can not use the `&`  to get the address of a local variable. You need to dynamically allocate a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the same memory is not allocated to all objects of a class... but the same memory **is** allocated for the local variables of every function. Once a function returns, all its local variables are destroyed, so its local variable memory is now unused, and the next function call will use it for its local variables. Hence every time you call `insertNode` it uses the same memory to hold `a`. And when you call `print`, it uses that same memory to hold `ptr`.

This is just what *usually* happens. Not all compilers do it the same way, so you can't rely on it. And if you had extra function calls between `main` and `insertNode` then `insertNode`'s variables wouldn't get the same addresses as they do when `main` calls `insertNode` directly.

Also note that because you aren't allowed to use pointers to variables that were already destroyed, the optimizer is allowed to guess that when you use a pointer, it points to a variable that hasn't been destroyed, and sometimes this causes really weird behaviour. So you mustn't use pointers to destroyed variables, ever, even if you would be okay with getting the wrong data. The technical term is *undefined behaviour*.